# Ubuntu screen resolution keeps resetting after restart

Tags: ubuntu, display, resolution, nvidia-graphics-card, wubi

I'm running Ubuntu 12.10 (Wubi) with an NVIDIA card I want my screen resolution to be at 1920x1200. I set this by opening the NVIDIA X Server Settings, going to X Server Display Configuration, then I set the resolution to 1920x1200 and hit apply and the correct resolution is set.

However, once I restart the computer, the resolution resets to 1024x768. How can I make it so it stays at 1920x1200 constantly? I tried using the "Save to X Configuration File" feature to save over /etc/X11/xorg.conf but it still resets to 1024x768 on restart. I also tried completely overwriting xorg.conf and merging it. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You have installed the current Nivida drivers correct?

Comment: Could you post the relevant section of the `xorg.conf`file? Also, perhaps Unity (the Ubuntu Desktop Environment) has its own setting for this. Look around the settings app in Ubuntu and try setting the resolution there. It should be under "Monitors" or something similar.

Comment: Did you found a solution? Im having the exact same problem. With my hdmi cable, but even with vmware. Tried different versions of ubuntu in vmware, but all reset back to the default resolution.